# sql query with group by and count

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

I have this ms access query:

```
SELECT weber, t1.artnr, t1.varnr, t1.lfdnr_kal, fert.invnr, fert.min, fert.[lst/h] FROM (
SELECT stammdat.weber, lackzahlen.artnr, lackzahlen.varnr, first(stammdat.[lfdnr-kal]) AS lfdnr_kal
FROM lackzahlen LEFT JOIN stammdat ON (lackzahlen.artnr=cstr(IIf(stammdat.artnr Is Null,'',cstr(stammdat.artnr)))) AND (lackzahlen.varnr=cstr(IIf(stammdat.varnr Is Null,'',cstr(stammdat.varnr)))) 
GROUP BY lackzahlen.artnr, lackzahlen.varnr, io_stkzahl, weber) AS t1
LEFT JOIN fert ON (t1.lfdnr_kal=fert.[lfdnr-kal]) AND (t1.artnr=cstr(iif(fert.artnr Is Null,'',cstr(fert.artnr)))) WHERE fert.invnr IN ('338902', 'R20000')
```

Now, I would like to filter the records on the image:

[image]

As you see, I would like to have the records, where there is pro weber, artnr, varnr, lfdnr_kal and invnr more than one row with the same min and lst/h value.

I guess, I should use cound (maybe having count) and group by. But how?

In the example, I haven't marked all the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `group by` and `having` to get the duplicate rows

```
  GROUP BY weber, t1.artnr, t1.varnr, t1.lfdnr_kal, fert.invnr, fert.min, fert.[lst/h]
  having count(*) >1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below SQL : As you didnt mention sum or AVG values i guess distinct records will solve your problem.

```html
select weber, a.artnr,a.varnr, a.lfdnr_kal, a.invnr, a.min, a.lst_h
(
SELECT weber, t1.artnr, t1.varnr, t1.lfdnr_kal, fert.invnr, fert.min, fert.[lst/h] as lst_h FROM (
SELECT stammdat.weber, lackzahlen.artnr, lackzahlen.varnr, first(stammdat.[lfdnr-kal]) AS lfdnr_kal
FROM lackzahlen LEFT JOIN stammdat ON (lackzahlen.artnr=cstr(IIf(stammdat.artnr Is Null,'',cstr(stammdat.artnr)))) AND (lackzahlen.varnr=cstr(IIf(stammdat.varnr Is Null,'',cstr(stammdat.varnr)))) 
GROUP BY lackzahlen.artnr, lackzahlen.varnr, io_stkzahl, weber) AS t1
LEFT JOIN fert ON (t1.lfdnr_kal=fert.[lfdnr-kal]) AND (t1.artnr=cstr(iif(fert.artnr Is Null,'',cstr(fert.artnr)))) WHERE fert.invnr IN ('338902', 'R20000')
) a group by weber, a.artnr,a.varnr, a.lfdnr_kal, a.invnr, a.min, a.lst_h 
Having count(*) > 1
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The question was not to remove the duplicated rows, but to get exactly those rows that have duplicates.